# heatmap to color image matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure

I have a grayscle image. I can create a heatmap in matlab using:

```
        I = imagesc(I);
```

it displays the intensity values in color. I want to get a color image using this heatmap. How can I do it?

This is the output of imagesc:[image: This is the output of imagesc]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Presumably by "color image" you mean an RGB or truecolor image (an image array with three color channels). And what you're calling a "heatmap" is the [`colormap`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html) that Matlab applies by default to grayscale images (image arrays with only one color channel). A grayscale image plus a color map is referred to as an indexed color image (read more about that [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/visualize/interpreting-indexed-and-truecolor-data.html)). You can use the [`ind2rgb`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2rgb.html) function to convert from indexed color to RGB:

```
IMG_gray = rand(100);
map = colormap; % Get the current colormap
IMG_rgb = ind2rgb(IMG_gray,map);
```

Note that by default the colormaps in Matlab use only 64 colors rather 256. To get smoother color gradations you can set the colormap manually via `map = colormap(jet(256));` or `map = colormap(hsv(256));`.

If you then want an image file, you can use [`imwrite`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html), which can take either RGB images or indexed color images with colormaps as input.

Comment: 'by default the colormaps in Matlab use only 64 colors rather 256' That, sir, is useful information. Thanks!

Comment: @Jigg: I know. It is 2014 after all! Hopefully they'll change it some day. Maybe when the new [Handle Graphics 2](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/hg2-update/) is released.

Answer (score 5):

Scale the intensity values in your image as `imagesc` does, and use a colormap (`jet` is default):

```
N = 256;
IN = round(N * (I-min(I(:)))/(max(I(:))-min(I(:))));
cmap = jet(N); % see also hot, etc.
IRGB = ind2rgb(IN,cmap);
```